# problems in loading up sencha stores with data on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I was able to load data into a store in sencha application from JSON files while running on a Desktop browser and ipad(using phonegap).

But when I try to run the application on an android device (using webView/phonegap) I am not able see any data. I am not sure whether it is loading data into stores or not. But it is not displaying any kind of data.

It is not even loading the icons provided by the sencha.

I found this message in Android Logs:

`I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2855): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27701 of [8609a15dfa], db=/data/data/com.app.ui/databases/webview.db`

Previously when the application is not even showing the screen, I modified the 'app.js' file to look like this (to disable the 'disableCaching').

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled: true,
disableCaching: false });     Ext.Ajax.setDisableCaching(false);
```

I am using Sencha Touch 2.0.0, Phone Gap 1.7.0 and Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.1).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using minified/compressed js of sencha then try to run with normal sencha-touch js.

I faced similar issue which was because of minified js, causes blank data and crashes the browser.

Not sure but might help you, Try it.

Comment: I am using Sencha-Touch-Debug.js and is not a minified/compressed one.